# Check date string and if more than 1 hour has passed

Tags: bash

I have a script that lists an IP based off the date `TIMENOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y-%H:%M")`

into my file `/root/deny.conf`

```
deny xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; # 03-03-2021-16:43
```

However I would like to know how can I pull the last line of `deny.conf` and check if more than 1 hour has passed since the last IP was added.

Example if the date is now `03-03-2021-17:43` or greater and the last listed line in `deny.conf` is `deny xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; # 03-03-2021-16:43` the value would be true and it would then bash another script called `/root/pass.sh`

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail?

Comment: You *really* want `%Y-%m-%d` formatting for any date you want to parse.

Comment: Are *any* of [these](https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time) relevant, or is this just a hack which doesn't care about things like daylight savings time?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a different timestamp; `+'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'` will let you do easy calculations and compares. For example:

```
date -d '2018-11-24 23:09 +1 hour' +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
```

gives `2018-11-25 00:09`.

`date` can also be used to convert to seconds since the beginning of time (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC), and of course, 1 hour is 3600 seconds.

If you don't want to change your timestamp, you will probably need to convert to something `date` accepts, for example:

```
timestamp='11-22-2021-16:43'
datepart=${timestamp%-*}
month=${datepart%%-*}
# etcetera
```

EDIT:
Your comment suggests that you need a bit more that the hints I gave above.

You could get the last date from the file with

```
timestamp=$(grep deny /root/deny.conf | tail -1 | sed 's/.*# *//')
```

You could convert this to seconds since EPOCH with

```
sects=$(date -d "$timestamp" '+%s')
```

and the current timestamp with:

```
now=$(date +%s)
```

and then

```
if [ $((sects+3600)) -le $now ] ; then
    echo "Long ago, in history almost forgotten"
else
    echo "Quite recent"
fi
```

Note that if you do a string compare, and you use the correct date format, that will also work:

```
timestamp=$(grep deny /root/deny.conf | tail -1 | sed 's/.*# *//')
hourago=$(date -d '1 hour ago') +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
if [ "$timestamp" > "$hourago" ] ; then
    echo "It just happened!"
else
    echo "Ancient history"
fi
```

Comment: How would I go about loading it from deny.conf if I used the ```date -d '2018-11-24 23:09 +1 hour' +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'``` option

Comment: See the update. of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update however it didn't seem to work. ```timestamp=$(grep deny /root/deny.conf | tail -1 | sed 's/.*# *//')
now=$(date +%s)
sects=$(date -d "$timestamp" '+%s')
if [ $((sects+3600)) -ge $now ] ; then
    echo "Long ago, in history almost forgotten"
else
    echo "Quite recent"
fi``` and in deny there is ```deny 34.211.25.xxx; # 2021-03-03 19:44```. It replies ```Long ago, in history almost forgotten```

Comment: Oops; that shouls have been `-le` in stead of `-ge`. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do you calculation based on the seconds since epoch for now and for the desired date.

```
#!/bin/bash
for last_line in "$(tail -n1 ./deny.log)"; do
    
    # skip the last line if empty
    [ "${#last_line}" -eq 0 ] && continue 

    # Getting only the date from the last line of input
    last_date=`grep -Po "(?<=# )(\d{2}-){2}\d{4}-\d{2}:\d{2}$" <<< $last_line`
    
    # LastDay : Assuming the first fiels represent the day
    ld=`cut -d- -f1 <<< $last_date`

    # LastMonth
    lm=`cut -d- -f2 <<< $last_date`

    # LastYear
    ly=`cut -d- -f3 <<< $last_date`

    # Last Hour and minute
    lh_m=`cut -d- -f4 <<< $last_date`

    # Build the date and get its time from epoch
    last_date_from_epoch=`date --date="${ly}-${lm}-${ld}T${lh_m}" +"%s"`

    # Get the 'now' time from epoch
    now=`date +"%s"`

    # The second in an hour
    hour_in_sec=$((60 * 60))

    # The difference, in seconds, from now and the last log
    difference=$((now - last_date_from_epoch))

    # If an hour, or more, is passed, call the script 
    [ "$difference" -lt "$hour_in_sec" ] || /root/pass.sh
done
```

Comment: Thanks this works really well however I noticed a small problem sometimes the last line of deny.conf is empty how can we change it so it will only read for the last line that has a date in it.

Comment: I think that a good approach check the emptyness of the last line of file in the caller. But if you wanna do that here you could put a check inside the `for` or use `sed` instead of `tail` to print the last line only if that is not empty

Comment: ```sed``` appears to have the same issue. How can I put a check inside ```for```?

Comment: edited for your request, could you try?